# Detecting exact instant when camera shutter is pressed iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I’ve searched a lot but cannot find how to programmatically detect when the camera shutter is pressed and the photo is actually taken.

UIImagePickerController doesn’t seem the way to go because it gets called before and dismissed after the photo is taken.  Any suggestion?

Comment: The time when the shutter is pressed is written into the photo metadata. Or if you need to intervene in real-time, substitute your own shutter button for the default shutter button.

Comment: Nice workaround! Thank you. I had not thought about this option!